# Is it possible to use a wildcard on the left of a LIKE ANY query in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

In the Postgres view I am querying I have an array property representing tags that have been assigned to a record. I want to be able to query that array for a fragment of an entry so that, for example, if the array contained `'abcdef', 'ghijk', 'lmnop'` I could query for `'%bcd%'` and find that record.

The current query looks like this: `SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE ('%abc%' ILIKE ANY (tags)` but that doesn't work at all. I can use the full match - `WHERE ('abcdef' ILIKE ANY (tags))` but I need to find data on a partial match as well.

At a pinch I could flatten the array into a string field in the view and use a regular `ILIKE` against that, but it feels a bit redundant when I already have the data there in the array.

Comment: No, you have to flatten, for example `select * from my_view where tags::text ~ '.*bcd.*';`

Comment: The approach given in the answers below does work, but a few tests with my dataset suggests that flattening is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

using the `unnest()` function you can unnest the array into individual elements and then perform the ILIKE comparison

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_view 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM unnest(tags) AS tag 
    WHERE tag ILIKE '%abc%'
);
```

The query will return all records from `my_view` where at least one tag in the tags array matches the pattern `'%abc%'`. It effectively achieves the partial match functionality you're looking for without needing to flatten the array into a string field.

Answer (score 1):

`unnest(tags)` function expands the array tags into a set of rows, each containing one tag.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_view
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM unnest(tags) AS tag
    WHERE tag ILIKE '%abc%'
);
```

**The WHERE clause inside the subquery checks if any of the tags in the expanded set match the pattern `%abc%` using the ILIKE operator.**